# AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'applyInPandas' in Azure Databricks

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I got stuck with the error while running some jobs on a DBR 6.6 ML cluster on Azure Databricks.
I've gone through the spark Grouped Map documentation and everything seems fine from my end.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was easily resolved by upgrading the cluster to a 7.0 ML